# problem with an autorun devserver 17 in windows startup on windows 10

Tags: windows, startup, easyphp, autorun, devserver

I have a program that builds with Delphi and It uses MySQL for DB in Windows 10. I install Devserver 17 but it can not be run in windows startup. I need to run Devserver before my program. I  searched on google and used some tips but my problem still alive. for example I use "shellexecuteEx" for run Devserver (run-devserver.exe) when my program start ( on FormCreat event) but it has a delay that is not good for me and give me a new PROBLEMS!. After running the "run-devserver.exe" with "shellexecuteEx", the Http server and database server aren`t  running! if I run them manually everything is ok but I want all of them (Devserver and HTTP server and database server) to start automatically before my program.
I use "shellexecuteEx" to execute "eds-dbserver.exe" too but it not working.
I think to avoid a chain of problems I should solve the first problem that is running Devserver and HTTP Server and Database server in Windows StartUp in Windows 10.
I used some tips that not worked for me (in the below):

```
-Using "shellexecuteEx",
-Run as Administrator,
-change "eds.ini" file : set "Autostart_httpserver=1" and "Autostart_dbserver=1"
-check the windows and antivirus firewall rules
-Run Programs Automatically Using Windows Task Scheduler
```

please give me a new way.

Comment: If you need a [service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/services), go ahead and implement a service.

Comment: I create a new service in CMD (as administrator ) but it gives me error 1053 and I used some tip about it (https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-error-1053-the-service-did-not-respond-to-the-start-or-control-request-in-a-timely-fashion/) but it not work .. I really disappointed

Answer (score 2):

I had to uninstall devserver 17 and install it again. I put a shortcut of "run-devserver.exe" in the startup folder in this address: `"C:\Users\MyPCName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"`. the Devserver started on windows startup but HTTP server and database server didn't start. i put a shortcut of dbserver and httpserver to the startup folder too and everything is ok!

dbserver address : `C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-binaries\dbserver\mysqlxxxx\bin\eds-dbserver.exe`

http server address :
`C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-binaries\httpserver\apachexxxx\bin\eds-httpserver.exe`